# how to remove object from map cobsidering method associated with the class of that object in java

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a class `Employee` which has attributes (`String designation, String name, int employeeID, Date dob, float salary`) and another class `Hobby` which has attributes (`String hobbyName, String hobbyDescription`)

The program should take the details of the employee and his/her hobbies as input and then store them as key/value pair in the map... I've done this.

Now the user should be able to delete all the details of an employee based on the id of the employee.

I've tried as follows. but it is erroneous

```
public void deleteEmployee(int id, Map<Employee,Hobby> m1)
{
    if(m1.containsKey((Employee.getEmployeeID())==id)) /*getEmployeeID() is the method in 'Employee' class which returns the Id of an employee*/
        m1.remove(Employee);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't do a comparison within the `#containsKey` method, but instead pass it the value of what you stored it under.

For instance, if you have a `Map<Integer, Employee>`, you could have something with a key of `101` pointing to an `Employee` object that has the id `101`. So operating with that in mind:

```
Map<Integer, Employee> map = /* your map field, from wherever */;
Employee emp = /* your employee with id 101 */;
map.put(emp.getId(), emp); //maps "101" to the Employee with ID "101"
Employee temp = map.get(emp.getId()); //We know for sure this would be the same as "emp"
temp = map.get(101); //This should also be the same object
```

That all being said, if you want to simply check if the object is there for the sake of removing it, you can easily just call `#remove` directly and compare the return value

```
if (map.remove(101) == null) { //or map.remove(emp.getId())
    //previous value did not exist, or was set manually to null
} else {
    //value was removed from map
}
```

Reading up on how the map interface works in Java would be quite a bit of help as well: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html

Per your design, instead of a random map holding data, why not just store the Hobbies in a `Set` inside the `Employee` class?:

```
public class Employee {

    private final Set<Hobby> hobbies; //The employee's hobbies
    //other fields/methods/etc

}
```